# Facebook Android SDK (v12.0.0) + Jetpack Compose + startActivityForResult(deprecated)

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, android-jetpack-compose, startactivityforresult

I'm developing a new Android app with Jetpack Compose and I want to add Facebook login. The latest version of the SDK (v12.0.0) supports the AndroidX activity results API but the documentation is not updated, does anyone know where I can get some example to be able to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69114788/9715339

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I don't want to use the onActivityResult flow which is deprecated, I want to use the AndroidX flow.

Comment: If the issue is with the documentation you should probably report it to Facebook so they update it.

Comment: As I said at the end of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69114788/3585796), you can use a fork made by enthusiast which supports new flow. But if you don't wanna do that, you have to wait for SDK update. Using a deprecated methods is not something bad, you can do it in cases like this one, when you have to use a library which is not yet adopted to new features.