# How to get handle update result of in-App updates

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, startactivityforresult, in-app-update

Issue,

> 'onActivityResult(Int, Int, Intent?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

As per [in-app update docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#status-callback), the given method requires `onActivityResult` but that is deprecated.

I can't find any details on how to use `registerForActivityResult` for the in-app updates.

P.S: I am using Jetpack compose. Relevant answers would be helpful.

**Note:**
I am well aware that this is not an error but a warning. I am using Jetpack compose and hence this is an issue for me as having activity results makes the code outside Compose.

Comment: See how I've done it for Facebook in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107068/facebook-login-with-jetpack-compose), should work for any library which haven't provided new API so far.

Comment: The answer is passing the data using a callback back to compose. It still uses the deprecated method `onActivityResult`. I am trying to avoid it completely.

Comment: @Abhimanyu did you found a solution for it yet?

Comment: @AkshayAshok, no 

Comment: As always documentation from google is outdated. The old method should still work.  You have your single Activity for creating compose app and you can use that for creating code for updating.

Comment: We can't treat this very lightly, even though this is a warning, it overrides ActivityResultContracts being used throughout the app.