# Jetpack compose listing for onActivityResult (Google Wallet Integration)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-pay

I started to add Add to Google wallet functionality to my compose App, when doing the push provision tokenisation , I'm stuck since they're still using the deprecated onActivityResult instead of the new contract api.

```
PushTokenizeRequest pushTokenizeRequest = new PushTokenizeRequest.Builder()
    .setOpaquePaymentCard(opc)
    .setNetwork(cardNetwork)
    .setTokenServiceProvider(tokenProvider)
    .setDisplayName("My Card")
    .setLastDigits("1234")
    .setUserAddress(userAddress)
    .build();

tapAndPayClient.pushTokenize(
    activity, // here i'm passing my current activity. 
    pushTokenizeRequest,
    REQUEST_CODE_PUSH_TOKENIZE);
```

Documentation says to implement this method on Activity, But i'm not sure how to get this value to my composeScreen.

```
Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PUSH_TOKENIZE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
      // TODO: Handle provisioning failure here.
      return;
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      // TODO: Handle successful provisioning here.
      String tokenId = data.getStringExtra(TapAndPay.EXTRA_ISSUER_TOKEN_ID);
      return;
    }
  }
  // TODO: Handle results for other request codes.
  // ...
}
```

Comment: found this SO question similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107068/facebook-login-with-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a state-tracking variable in your ViewModel, and update it when `onActivityResult()` is triggered. And in your Composable, observe that variable for changes. Something like this:

In your ViewModel:

```
var walletResult = MutableLiveData(0)
```

In onActivityResult():

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
    viewModel.walletResult.postVlue(-1)
} else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    viewModel.walletResult.postVlue(1)
}
```

And in your Composable:

```
val walletResult by viewModel.walletResult.observeAsState(0)
LaunchedEffect(walletResult){
    if(walletResult > 0){
        // trigger positive response notification
    }else if(walletResult < 0){
        // trigger negative response notification
    }
    
    // reset the value back to neutral
    viewModel.walletResult.postVlue(0)
}
```